# How to set no. of rows limit for pandas dataframe Maximum function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 100 rows in column B but I want to find Maximum value for only 99 rows.

If I use the below code it returns maximum value from 100 rows instead of 99 rows:

```
print(df1['noc'].max(axis=0))
```

Comment: `df1['noc'].iloc[0:99].max(axis=0)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.head.html) or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for select first `99` values and then get `max`:

```
print(df1['noc'].head(99).max())
```

Or as commented [`IanS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032263/how-to-set-no-of-rows-limit-for-pandas-dataframe-maximum-function#comment79024331_46032263):

```
print (df1['noc'].iloc[:99].max())
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(15)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'noc':np.random.randint(10, size=15)})
print (df1)
    noc
0     8
1     5
2     5
3     7
4     0
5     7
6     5
7     6
8     1
9     7
10    0
11    4
12    9
13    7
14    5

print(df1['noc'].head(5).max()) 
8

print (df1['noc'].iloc[:5].max())
8

print (df1['noc'].values[:5].max())
8
```